How do my phrases is not zooming in Android
I have two phrases:
When I use Android.
I open Settings > Display > Font size and style > Font size > I get {max size}.
Then I go to Chrome and open my website, h3 is working normal, but div is not woking, it is zoomed, can you help me?
Thank you!


h3 {
  font-size:1rem;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  & span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
}

div {
  font-size:1rem;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  & span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
<h3><span>Chat Community</span></h3>
<div><span>Find the best course near you! Check your distance, plan your next shot with detailed hole views and measure your most impressive drives.</span></div>




This doesn't look like CSS, more like SCSS or LESS. How are you compiling to plain CSS?

In this case it would be useful to have some screenshots as to what you mean, because if your CSS compiles/is valid (the & selector is not yet supported but will be in the future), the change of font size on the system would apply to all elements. There is no "exception" and definitely not for just the div element (which has no predetermined user agent font size set)
